# how to get uitextview text in particular area

Tags: ios, text, uitextview, area, rect

i need to get text from uitextview. The text i need is in particular area after scrolling the textview, not all the text in uitextview.
i'll describe what i need in some images.

first, i have this textview 
[image]

then, i want to get some text, like in this image : 
[image]

but i dont know how to do that, can somebody help me ?
thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(desired_position, 0);
[myTextview setSelectedRange:range];
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting and unusual question.

[Rewrite for UITextView, originally written for UITextField]

A UITextView is basically a text input control wrapped in a UIScrollView ( using inheritance).  A UIScrollView works by moving it's contents around using the co-ordinates of it's view around relative to it's frame.

Look at the contentOffset of the UITextView to get the amount of vertical scrolling that has occurred ( the text has scrolled up, so the y value will be negative.)

Once you have the amount of scrolling, you need to get the font for the UITextView.  Use NSString sizeWithFont to get the height of a line.  Divide the y-coordinate by the line height and that will give you how many newlines to skip.

The end of the visible text is a little different.  Depending on your controller structure, the UITextView may have been resized, or not.  If you're using a UITableViewController, for example, it will typically resize the tableView automatically.  I'm going to assume that you have resized the UITextView, in which case the end 'y' is the start 'y' + the textView.frame.size.height.  If you haven't resized the UITextView to fit the space above the keyboard, then you change the design to do so, or subtract the size of the on screen keyboard.

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for the response, but that is uitextview not uitextfield :)

can you tell me what view that i have to translate?

Comment: Thanks R, for pointing that out.  It enabled me to improve my rather inadequate first answer.